# PyTorch (GPU) slower than CPU slower than keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I'm just getting started with PyTorch and I wanted to run through a few toy problems. In the following case, I'm noticing a significant difference in how much time it takes for the model to train once over and issue one batch of predictions.

This is the PyTorch implementation. On the GPU, it takes ~17 seconds on my machine. The same model on the CPU takes ~11 seconds.

```
class LR(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(2, 20)
        self.linear2 = torch.nn.Linear(20, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.linear2(x))
        return x


def fit_torch(df_train, df_test):
    sampler_tr = torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler(df_train.index)
    train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        torch.tensor(df_train.values, dtype=torch.float),
        batch_size=batch_size, sampler=sampler_tr)

    sampler_te = torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler(df_test.index)
    test = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        torch.tensor(df_test.values, dtype=torch.float),
        batch_size=batch_size, sampler=sampler_te)

    model = LR()
    model = model.to(device)

    loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

    model.train()
    for _ in range(1000):
        for train_data in train:
            train_data = train_data.to(device)

            x_train = train_data[:, :2]
            y_train = train_data[:, 2]

            optim.zero_grad()

            pred = model(x_train)
            loss_val = loss(pred.squeeze(), y_train)

            loss_val.backward()
            optim.step()

    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for test_data in test:
            test_data = test_data.to(device)

            pred = model(test_data[:, :2].float())
            break
```

This is the keras implementation. It takes approximately 9 seconds to run.

```
def fit_tf(df_train, df_test):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(
        df_train.values[:, :2],
        df_train.values[:, 2],
        batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1000, verbose=0)

    model.predict(df_test.iloc[:batch_size].values[:, :2])
```

The dataset and **main** functions.

```
device = torch.device('cuda:0')
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

batch_size = 64

def create_dataset():
    dataset = []    
    random_x = np.random.randint(10, 1000, 1000)
    random_y = np.random.randint(10, 1000, 1000)

    for x, y in zip(random_x, random_y):
        dataset.append((x, y, 4 * x + 3 * y + 10))

    np.random.shuffle(dataset)
    df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
    df = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df))

    return df

def __main__():
    df = create_dataset()
    df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df)

    start_time = time.time()
    fit_tf(df_train.reset_index(drop=True), df_test.reset_index(drop=True))
    print(time.time() - start_time)
```

Comment: You are using  `model.predict(df_test.iloc[:batch_size].values[:, :2])`, hence you are using a single batch in testing in Keras, while using whole test set in PyTorch. Also what is your `batch_size` exactly? Also what is your GPU?

Comment: The `batch_size` is 64 (from the last segment of code). Also, the PyTorch evaluation loop breaks after the first batch.
I also ran it without the testing and the difference persists regardless (8.1s for keras on GPU and 16.5s for PyTorch on GPU). This is on a Quadro RTX 5000.

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch uses a dynamic computational graph by default, which is more flexible when you start to develop a neural network since it will give a more straight forward debug message. TensorFlow, in contrast, will produce a static computational graph, and that is why you need to compile the model before use it. The compiler can optimize your model, but the tradeoff is the neural network becomes difficult to debug. This may cause minor difference between the performance of the two framework, but should not be a big deal.

Since your network is pretty small, the overhead to copy the network between GPU memory and CPU memory and to initiate the CUDA subsystem exceeds the benefit brought by the GPU. If you try some more complex neural network such as AlexNet, ResNet or even GoogLeNet, the benefit will be much more obvious.

Comment: "Tensorflow is faster by default" - I'm not aware of research/benchmarks showing this. Usually those go either way, while performance of both frameworks is comparable on average, especially in this case. Also copying of such small network is unlikely to have any impact on overall run time.

Comment: Well, I mean in general TensorFlow can produce a more optimized computational graph through its compiler. And you are right that copying itself will not have a huge compact, but CUDA subsystem also needs some time to be initialized.

Comment: Compiler optimizations are minimal and hardly have any effect, kernels themselves are already highly specialized in C++, maybe using XLA or related.